# Pushbutton 120 V switch

Tags: switches, wiring

Can I use this push button switch for a house lamp that runs on 120 V? If so, do I need a contactor or can I wire it direct?

[image: details]

[image: wiring diagram]

Answer (score 0):

**If** the house wiring is 120 VAC, and the load is below 5 A (note that the inrush to a motor or incandescent lamp may be five times that when running), it *might* work as is, without a relay. However, it does not state if the switch meets *safety standards*, e.g., [RU](https://www.powerelectric.com/ul-ur-mark), which might be a concern if used on an appliance connected to the mains.

One thing I might be concerned about is narrow spacing of connectors, with 120 VAC across them, and possible higher voltage surges. Also, is the push-button metallic? Will it be used in a grounded (earthed) metallic box?